# Rectangle bar chart design on dynamic value

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, d3.js, bar-chart

I would like to develop a design using ReactJS where the sum of values on each side will be 100% and values will divided into 3 sections which can be dynamic

The middle section should be maintained as per the value as shown in the image.

Here is my Code

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const CONTAINER_HEIGHT = 450;

export const ParentDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;
export const OverLay = styled.div`
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
`;

export const PercentageDivContainer = styled.div`
  height: ${(): string => `${CONTAINER_HEIGHT}px`};
`;

export const PercentageDivContainerMID = styled.div`
  width: 140px;
`;

export const PercentageDiv = styled.div`
  width: 70px;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
`;

export const hexToRgbA = (hex: string, opacity: number = 1): string => {
  let color: any;
  const pattern = /^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(hex);
  if (pattern) {
    color = hex.substring(1).split('');
    if (color.length == 3) {
      color = [color[0], color[0], color[1], color[1], color[2], color[2]];
    }
    color = '0x' + color.join('');
    return 'rgba(' + [(color >> 16) & 255, (color >> 8) & 255, color & 255].join(',') + ',' + opacity + ')';
  }
  throw new Error('Bad Hex');
};

const createChartComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const borderTrangle = {
    // http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/
    topToLeft: {
      borderWidth: '-x- 140px 0 0',
      borderColor: '-x- transparent transparent transparent',
    },
    topToRight: {
      borderWidth: '0 140px -x- 0',
      borderColor: 'transparent -x- transparent transparent',
    },
    bottomToLeft: {
      borderWidth: '-x- 0 0 140px',
      borderColor: ' transparent transparent transparent -x-',
    },
    bottomToRight: {
      borderWidth: '0 0 -x- 140px',
      borderColor: 'transparent transparent -x- transparent',
    },
  };

  const data = {
    users: [
      {
        p: 40,
      },
      {
        p: 40,
      },
      {
        p: 20,
      },
    ],
    usage: [
      {
        p: 35.7,
      },
      {
        p: 35.2,
      },
      {
        p: 29.1,
      },
    ],
  };

  const { users, usage } = data;

  const getTriangleHeight = (leftPercentage, rightPercentage) => {
    const maxHeightForMiddle = Math.max(...[leftPercentage, rightPercentage]);

    // Calculate the heights based on percentages and the container width
    const leftHeight = (leftPercentage * CONTAINER_HEIGHT) / 100;
    const rightHeight = (rightPercentage * CONTAINER_HEIGHT) / 100;

    // Calculate the triangle height by subtracting rightHeight from leftHeight
    const triangleHeight = Math.abs(leftHeight - rightHeight);
    return {
      triangleHeight,
      maxHeightForMiddle,
      isLeftValueGreater: leftPercentage < rightPercentage,
    };
  };

  const createBorderCurveFunc = (data) => {
    const { users, usage } = data;
    if (users.length !== usage.length) return;

    const { topToRight, topToLeft, bottomToLeft, bottomToRight } = borderTrangle;

    return Array.from({ length: users.length }).map((_, index) => {
      let currentTrangle = getTriangleHeight(users[index]?.p, usage[index]?.p);
      let isPositiveValue = currentTrangle.isLeftValueGreater ? [topToRight, bottomToLeft] : [topToLeft, bottomToRight];
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            height: `${currentTrangle.maxHeightForMiddle}%`,
            position: 'relative',
          }}
        >
           <>
              <OverLay
                style={{
                  borderColor: isPositiveValue[0].borderColor.replace('-x-', `blue`),
                  borderWidth: isPositiveValue[0].borderWidth.replace('-x-', `${currentTrangle.triangleHeight}px`),
                }}
              ></OverLay>
              <OverLay
                style={{
                  borderColor: isPositiveValue[1].borderColor.replace('-x-', `red`),
                  borderWidth: isPositiveValue[1].borderWidth.replace('-x-', `${currentTrangle.triangleHeight}px`),
                }}
              ></OverLay>
            </>
        </div>
      );
      // }
    });
  };

  const getColor = (color, index) => hexToRgbA(color, index === 0 ? 1 : 1 - index * 0.33);

  return (
    <ParentDiv>
      <PercentageDivContainer>
        {users.map((item, index) => (
          <PercentageDiv style={{ height: `${item.p}%`, backgroundColor: getColor('#007bff', index) }}>{item.p}</PercentageDiv>
        ))}
      </PercentageDivContainer>
      <PercentageDivContainerMID>{createBorderCurveFunc(data)}</PercentageDivContainerMID>
      <PercentageDivContainer>
        {usage.map((item, index) => (
          <PercentageDiv style={{ height: `${item.p}%`, backgroundColor: getColor('#007bff', index) }}>{item.p}</PercentageDiv>
        ))}
      </PercentageDivContainer>
    </ParentDiv>
  );
};

export default createChartComponent;
```

I am currently working on creating a border triangle.
To make that middle section shape first I compare the maximum height between the left and right percentages, which is 81.1% in our case. Since it is a significant value, I set the middle element height to be 81.1% and inside that, I place 2 divs as absolute on which I am creating a border shape. Then, I calculate the necessary difference to create the border triangle to match the edges and position it with absolute at the bottom. For the first iteration, it turned out perfectly for both the cases if left > right ya right > left. However,
I am facing challenges in determining how to position the element and border triangle for the second and third placements. Here is the output of the code.

[image]
[image]

JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mfaraz7448/eoj9Lkv5/

Comment: Hey Mohammad, Thanks for the detailed question but it would help you get a good answer if you could show us the demo with the code. Maybe you can use an external service like CodeSandbox.

Comment: Hi @m4n0, i have added the JSfillde link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code doesn't use `d3.js` but I assume you are open to such a solution since you tagged the question with it.  I think trying to create such a visualization with html and divs is the wrong tool for the job.

Your mock-up, to me, just looks like a fancied up stacked bar chart so I created the chart as such.  The difficult part is really all the custom labels.  I've commented below so hopefully it is self-explanatory:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.5/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>
      const margin = { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 20 },
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const svg = d3
        .select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

      var tooltip = d3
        .select('#chart')
        .append('div')
        .style('position', 'absolute')
        .style('visibility', 'hidden')
        .style('background-color', 'white')
        .style('padding', '20px')
        .style('font-family', 'sans-serif')
        .style('font-size', '12pt')
        .text('');

      const data = {
        users: [
          {
            p: 20,
          },
          {
            p: 40,
          },
          {
            p: 40,
          },
        ],
        usage: [
          {
            p: 5,
          },
          {
            p: 15,
          },
          {
            p: 80,
          },
        ],
      };

      // in order to use d3.stack, we need the data in the format of...
      // [ {p1: 40, p2: 40, p3: 20}, {p1: 35.7, p2: 35.2, p3: 29.1} ]
      const stackableData = [
        data.users.reduce((a, d, i) => {
          a[i] = d.p;
          return a;
        }, {}),
        data.usage.reduce((a, d, i) => {
          a[i] = d.p;
          return a;
        }, {}),
      ];

      // let d3 do the stack magic.  This essentially calculates rolling sums at each array position
      const keys = Object.keys(stackableData[0]);
      const stackedData = d3.stack().keys(keys)(stackableData);

      // set up our scales.  For the x we are just using two columns
      // adjust padding to make the "flow" part wider/narrower
      const x = d3.scaleBand().domain([0, 1]).range([0, width]).padding([0.5]);
      // y scale assumes both stacks are 100%
      const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([height, 0]);

      // colors...
      const color = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(keys)
        .range(['#5E7AC5', '#9AACDB', '#3456B1']);

      // draw the 6 rectangles of our stacks
      svg
        .selectAll(null)
        .data(stackedData)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'pair')
        .attr('fill', (d) => color(d.key))
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data((d) => d)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', (d, i) => x(i))
        .attr('y', (d) => y(d[1]))
        .attr('height', (d) => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
        .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
        .on('mouseover', (e,d,i,j) => {
          tooltip.html(d[1] - d[0] + '%')
          return tooltip.style('visibility', 'visible');
        })
        .on('mousemove', (e) => {
          const [x, y] = d3.pointer(e);
          return tooltip
            .style('top', (y-50) + 'px')
            .style('left', x + 'px');
        })
        .on('mouseout', (d,i) => {
          return tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden');
        });

      // draw the "flow" between the stacks
      d3.selectAll('.pair')
        .append('polygon')
        .attr('points', (d, i) => {
          let r1 = d[0],
            r2 = d[1],
            rv = '';
          rv += x(0) + x.bandwidth() + ',' + y(r1[0]) + ' ';
          rv += x(0) + x.bandwidth() + ',' + y(r1[1]) + ' ';
          rv += x(1) + ',' + y(r2[1]) + ' ';
          rv += x(1) + ',' + y(r2[0]) + ' ';
          return rv;
        })
        .attr('fill-opacity', 0.8);

      // hacky part here, add all the custom labels
      // since the "y-axis" is in the same y position as the percent, hack that in
      [0, 0, 1].forEach((j, k) => {
        d3.selectAll('.pair')
          .append('text')
          .text((d, i) =>
            k == 0 ? ['Light', 'Medium', 'Heavy'][i] : d[j].data[i] + '%'
          )
          .attr('font-size', '14')
          .attr('font-family', 'sans-serif')
          .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
          .attr('x', (d, i) =>
            k == 0 ? margin.left : x(j) + x.bandwidth() / 2
          )
          .attr('y', (d, i) => {
            let r = d[j];
            return (y(r[0]) - y(r[1])) / 2 + y(r[1]);
          })
          .attr('dy', '0.71em')
          .attr('fill', k == 0 ? 'black' : 'white')
          .attr('fill-opacity', (d, i, t) => {
            // if the text element overflows the rect
            // hide it by setting opacity to 0
            let elem = t[i],
              r = d[j];
            return elem.getBBox().height > (y(r[0]) - y(r[1])) / 2 ? 0 : 1;
          });
      });

      // "x-axis"
      svg
        .selectAll(null)
        .data(['Users', 'Usage'])
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .text((d) => d)
        .attr('x', (d, i) => x(i) + x.bandwidth() / 2)
        .attr('font-size', '14')
        .attr('font-family', 'sans-serif')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('y', height)
        .attr('dy', '1.1em');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, thank you so much, for the solution you provided this is exactly what I want to achieve I appreciate your efforts, 1 more thing I want to know how we do if the percentage is < 7 hide the number and custom tooltip where we can render our own html

Comment: @MohammadFaraz, see updates above.  For the "hide the number" I based it on calculating if the text was going to overflow the rect.  This is better than basing it on value as it allows you to adjust the size of the chart.

Comment: Hi @Mark, 
I am able to customize it as per my requirement, the tooltip and custom labels, 
I appreciated the help you did thank you a ton man. Also would like to buy coffee for you, please let me know.
waiting for your positive response